# Какой системный вызов нужен, чтоб игнорировать сигналы операционной системы?

Tags: c, unix

Когда соккет закрывается, а я программа продолжает в него писать, вылетает prokenpipe. Как этого избежать и игнорировать сигнал?

Comment: [man sigprocmask](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sigprocmask.2.html) (see also [man 7 signal](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

чтобы посмотреть какие есть сигналы, можно написать `kill -l`.
чтобы заблокировать сигнал, то пишите.

```
#include <signal.h>

signal ( SIGPIPE, SIGIGN );
```